# Searching for Parse objects where an object's array property contains a specified string

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery, nosql

I have a PFObject subclass which stores an array of strings as one of its properties. I would like to query for all objects of this class where one or more of these strings **start with** a provided substring.

An example might help:

I have a `Person` class which stores a `firstName` and `lastName`. I would like to submit a `PFQuery` that searches for `Person` objects that match on name. Specifically, a person should be be considered a match if if any ‘component’ of either the first or last name start with the provided search term.

For example, the name "Mary Beth Smith-Jones" should be considered a match for `beth` and `bet`, but not `eth`.

To assist with this, I have a `beforeSave` trigger for the `Person` class that breaks down the person's first and last names into separate components (and also lowercases them). This means that my "Mary Beth Smith-Jones" record looks like this:

`firstName`: “Mary Beth”

`lastName`: “Smith-Jones”

`searchTerms`: [“mary”, “beth”, “smith”, “jones”]

The closest I can get is to use `whereKey:EqualTo` which will actually return  matches when run against an array:

```
    let query = Person.query()
    query?.whereKey(“searchTerms”, equalTo: “beth”)
    query?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (places, error) -> Void in
        //Mary Beth is retuned successfully
    })
```

However, this only matches on full string equality; `query?.whereKey(“searchTerms”, equalTo: “bet”)` does not return the record in question.

I suppose I could explode the names and store all possible sequential components as search terms (`b`,`e`,`t`,`h`,`be`,`et`,`th`,`bet`,`etc`,`beth`, etc) but that is far from scalable.

Any suggestions for pulling these records from Parse? I am open to changing my approach if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `whereKey:hasPrefix:` for this? I am not sure if this can be used on array values.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-queries-on-string-values

Comment: I have - it can only be used on strings. Thanks though.

Comment: And your values are...?

Comment: `hasPrefix` can only be applied to a string column. My column is an **array** of strings.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that part. I don't believe there is a way to directly do this. If this is crucial, you will probably have to use a contrived solution like the one you suggested: store "Smith" as [s,sm,smi,smit,smith] etc. I'm sorry I can't suggest a better solution :-/